# Make the CC Collider follow the camera (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So I made a script that should In theory make the Character Controller's Collider follow the Player camera. Here is the Script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class CCCameraFollower : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Camera;
    public CharacterController character;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        character.center = Camera.transform.position;
    }
}
```

This works Fine/Okay when I try it out, however as soon as I enter `Climb()` In my Climber script:

```cs
    void Climb()
    {
        InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(climbingHand.controllerNode)
            .TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.deviceVelocity, out Vector3 velocity);

        character.Move(transform.rotation * -velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        cachedVelocity = -velocity;
        Debug.Log(cachedVelocity);
    }
```

When this is `Climb()` Runs, this happens:
[Image that Shows The Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHQwt.png)

I don't see a reason for this to happen, maybe its very obvious. I don't know... Anyways, my question is: "How do I make the Collider of the CC Follow the Player Camera?".

Answer (score 0):

In the CCCameraFollower.LateUpdate() method you are actually moving the center of the character controller and not the position of the Camera. Change to this and it will probably work as you want.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    Camera.transform.position = character.center;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this sort of worked. Basically,  in the VR Headset itself it's fine, however in the Scene thing on the PC, the camera itself doent move, I dont know how to add an image to imgur so ye sorry.

Comment: Also, when moving around IRL the collider also doesn't change position, while it does in the camera